# Site looks odd in Opera

Tags: bug

Yup, that's about it. I hope this is the right channel through which to let you know.

Oddly it looks fine in Opera Mobile though, both when I identify as Mobile and Desktop.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dKI7.png

Comment: I've tried Opera 11.60 on Windows 7 and I couldn't seem to find the problem. Which operating system and browser version are you using? In what way does it look odd? If possible, I think adding a screenshot could help with diagnosing this.

Comment: I'm running Opera 11.61 (and also Opera Next, currently 12.00 alpha) under Arch Linux. It's just pale and fonts are "off". I'll upload a screen shot in a minute.

Comment: hmm... I tried Opera 11.61 on Ubuntu 10.04 and it seems to work OK. I think it may be that fonts aren't installed or some kind of font-rendering problem on your computer. Do you have the same problem in Google Chrome/Firefox etc as you do in Opera?

Comment: Might be as simple as that. Works fine in Chromium, but I'll look into if Opera doesn't find the fonts or something.

Comment: Right, installing Microsoft fonts solved the issue. Still, may not be a bad idea to provide embedded fonts?

Comment: Can you see if you have "Bitstream Vera Sans" installed on your Arch Linux distro, please?  It's mentioned in the [font config wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration#Replace_fonts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Microsoft fonts solved the issue.